# Is there a reason why my VScode CLI doesnt recognise standard commands?

Tags: visual-studio-code, gcc

I am inputing commands into my CLI to run my source code yet it doesn't recognise these standard commands. I have updated my includepath, that became effective as I noticed the squiggles no longer appeared under the text in my source code, but I am unable to run my code from the command terminal for some reason. For some context, I am using C language. My question please is what could be the reason why linux os refuses to understand simple commands such as ' g++ --version'? Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Are you in a *terminal* tab or potentially are you potentially in one of the other tabs like the *debug console*?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.